# Is it possible to do a "for each" loop in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, loop

I need to be able to feed each curve instance into the custom group node. Is it possible to do a `for each` loop in geometry nodes for each curve instance? Each curve instance represents one branch of my tree. I need to individually feed each branch into the group node through a loop. Is that possible?

[image]

Actually the leaves do position somewhat properly on the branches with just a small anomaly so i thought the loop didn't work. But it seems that the "looping" does work somehow with my setup. This anomaly is probably caused by so many splines for just 1 instance when i tested resampling the curve for only 1 instance. Any idea how 1 instance can have so many splines while the wireframe seems not to show this as a possibility?

[image]

Comment: no, until now there is no loop in GN. But maybe it is possible what you want if you tell us your endgoal instead of asking for a method?

Comment: oh that's a bummer. well i think it actually did "loop" somehow for each curve, i just thought it didn't work properly because i saw 528 splines for just 1 branch instance as shown in the new screenshot i attached. the main stem only has 1 spline, so im scratching my head why the branch ended up with 528 splines. any idea?

Comment: i have a file https://pasteall.org/blend/fae215baf52445e4aefb96a7794ff3b3 maybe you can help me?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? so what do you want to do with each curve? make a branch? randomize the shape of the branch?

Comment: oh it already works, you can increase the resample curve count from 3 to something like 10 to see more branches. the only problem i have is that there are too many splines 528 for some reason per branch. that is problem 1 im trying to resolve, then problem 2 is minor is that some leaves are pointing inwards instead of outwards. but leaves point properly outwards if they are the instance on the main stem instead of the branch. duno why that is XD

Comment: The problem is I think that all edges create a spline with 2 control points. Try adding a merge by distance node

Comment: yes you're probably right, i fixed it now, thank you guys for all your help :)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie It would be great of you to write a short answer to this and mark it as "Accepted Answer" so that this question shows up as solved. Thank you!

Comment: @quellenform I'm sorry I forgot to answer this. Unfortunately I don't remember how I solved it, but it was not related to the title. I think there is a loop now for version 4.0? Maybe you can add an answer to the title instead of the actual problem I had so at least the community has an answer to the actual title. hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this setup to iterate through pieces I created earlier with `Instance on Points`, and do a `Convex Hull` operation on each piece separately - this is essentially the `For each` setup you wanted:

[image]

And here's how I got the index and count:

[image]

Comment: Hello thank you for your response. Yes this is a new feature in Blender 4.0 :D